# How to get last item when i use map?

Tags: angular

I have this :

```
       this.orderTrackings.map((v:any)=>{
if(v == lastItem){doSomething(){}}
});
```

How can i get last item in map and do something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get this by using `index` in `map`:

```
this.orderTrackings.map((v:any, index)=>{
  if((index+1) == this.orderTrackings.length) { 
    doSomething(){}
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Be careful on what you ask !

This issue is about the map **operator**, but there's a map **type** that exists.

In your case, I guess you want to get the last item and process it in your map ?

This should suit you :

```
this.orderTrackings.map(v => {
  if(v === this.orderTrackings.slice(-1)) { doSomething(); }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 const rowLen = this.orderTrackings.length;
    this.orderTrackings.map((v, i) => {
      if (rowLen === i + 1) {
        // last one
      } else {
        // not last one
      }
    })
```